# Isothermal heat transfer processes are always reversible?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, time, reversibility

in my textbook, it is mentioned ;
" isothermal heat transfer processes are internally reversible "

what is the reason behind that?

Comment: What do they mean by "*internally* reversible" in your book?

Comment: I agree with Chet Miller's answer.

Answer (score 3):

For a process to be internally reversible, the Clausius inequality must be satisfied with the equality sign.  If the system is always isothermal throughout, then there cannot be temperature gradients within the system.  That means that the system temperature throughout must match the boundary temperature, and all heat transfer at the boundary must occur at the system temperature.  This means that Clausius inequality must satisfy the equality sign, and the process must therefore be internally reversible.

However, if by isothermal they mean only that the boundary temperature is constant and equal to the initial and final temperatures of the system, this would not necessarily guarantee an internally reversible process.

Comment: Supposing that there's no volumic heating, we have $\dot{S} \ge \int_{\text{boundary}}\frac{q}{T}\ \mathrm{d}a$ (where $q=-\pmb{q}\cdot \pmb{n}$  is the heat influx). How you deduce that we have an equality sign if $T$ doesn't depend on time or is uniform?

Comment: @pglpm If T is uniform, then the system temperature is equal to the temperature of the boundary.  If the system does work, the temperature within the system can still change relative to the boundary, and the temperature gradients within the system will cause entropy to be generated.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I mean I don't understand how you conclude that the process must be reversible.

Comment: @pglpm Maybe you can cite a specific example that we can focus on.

Comment: I don't follow your proof, so specific examples don't work here. Let's say the temperature is constant in space and time throughout the body. You say that then $\dot{S} = \int_{\text{boundary}} q/T \ \mathrm{d}a$, with an equality sign (reversible process). I don't see how this follows from the second law  $\dot{S} \ge \int_{\text{boundary}} q/T \ \mathrm{d}a$. Even if $T$ is constant in time and space, the strict inequality (irreverible process) in the second law can still hold.

Comment: @pglpm Please cite a specific example where T is constant in time and space, and the inequality holds.

Comment: Sorry but that's not how a theorem is proven, "cite a counterexample". Neither the second law nor the first law together imply your claim. The onus is on you to provide a proof. I can imagine systems with electromagnetic interactions or internal degrees of freedom such as intrinsic spin in which we have heat flows and constant temperature for finite intervals of time.

Comment: Maybe you're assuming a constitutive equation such as $\pmb{q} \propto -\nabla T$, but that's only that – a *constitutive* equation, not a universal law.

Comment: @pglpm You can image heat flow heat flow with no temperature driving force only when you imagine that the process itself is reversible. Otherwise, your imagination is leading you astray.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer (1) You're saying "$q\ne 0 \text{ and }\nabla T=0 \Longrightarrow \dot{S}=q/T$". Rather than simply repeating this over and over, can you cite a source where it's proven or prove it yourself? Otherwise it can be very well a product of your imagination. (2) Even if the temperature is constant and uniform, and even if there is no heat flux, all we're left with is $\dot{S}\ge 0$, and from this we can't deduce that $\dot{S}=0$. So the statement of the OP is not valid in general.

Comment: @pglpm In Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, they show that the instantaneous local rate of entropy generation within a system (neglecting mass transport and chemical reaction) is the sum of a term proportional to the square of the heat flux plus another term proportional to the rate of viscous dissipation (which varies with the square of the velocity gradients).  Both of these are insignificant in a reversible process and either are both of significant in an irreversible process.  Plus, they show that, in an irreversible process, the Clausius inequality is satisfied.(Cntnd)

Comment: In a truly isothermal process, there can be no temperature gradients within the system, and, energy conversion via viscous dissipation must be negligible (or temperature gradients will develop within the system).

Comment: @ChetMiller Thank you for the reference! that's simply what I wanted. I'll check out their assumptions and derivations.

Comment: @pglpm You're welcome.  To make life easier for you, see Chapter 11, exercise problem 11.D.1 Equation of change for entropy.  Also see the first few pages in the beginning of Chapter 24.

Comment: @ChetMiller I'm familiar with parts of that book and I like it a lot. To share a reference back, my observations are based on Astarita: [*Thermodynamics:
An Advanced Textbook for Chemical Engineers*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4899-0771-4). I find it brilliant, it sometimes considers more general situations than Bird & al's. But so far I've never found any contradictions between the two texts (when all due assumptions behind their statements are taken into account).

Comment: @pglpm Thanks for the reference.  I'll order myself a copy.

Comment: @pglpm The confusion may be in applying the term isothermal to mean constant in spatial extent rather than constant in time.

Comment: @pglpm  Here is a Thermodynamics textbook I highly recommend:  Introduction to Engineering Thermodynamics, Moran et al.  This book is available for download online (I think).

Comment: Thank you @ChetMiller I realize I have it in my e-library but never looked at it in detail. I will. Here's one back: Samohyl, Pekar: [*The Thermodynamics of Linear Fluids and Fluid Mixtures*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-02514-8). It emphasizes the role of frame-invariance (too often neglected in some books) and the role of the second law in constraining the general form of constitutive equations.

Answer (score 0):

In real systems, heat transfer occurs between two locations due to a temperature gradient or difference. How can heat transfer in an *isothermal process*?

During an *isothermal process*, temperature is constant *with time* in a location of interest. By comparison, in a *constant temperature system*, temperature is constant throughout a spatial region (and we have defined that spatial region as the system).

What is meant by "internally"? The three places to look are the system, the surroundings, and the universe (the combination). The boundary does not give or take of any role in thermodynamic analysis, it only serves to separate the system from the surroundings.

The restriction is to set "internal" as the system itself. We are not concerned with how the heat enters/leaves the system to the surroundings during the process, only with how the heat is transported inside the system itself.

The final crux is this.

**A system that has temperature gradients inside of it does not have one unique thermodynamic state. Such a system therefore cannot be used to carry out isothermal processes (processes that are to keep the system's temperature constant with time)**.

We conclude that, when temperature is to be kept constant in the system during all times during a process, it must also be constant instantaneously throughout the defined system at any point in time during the process. Essentially, we must define our system as being the smallest spatial region that has a constant temperature throughout so that we can also establish a process that will have a constant temperature with time.

What is a reversible process? It is one where the system and its surroundings are in thermal, mechanical, and chemical equilibrium at any instant in time during any step in the process.

We have a system with constant temperature throughout. We transfer heat into or out of that system. The heat transfer does not change the temperature of the system over the time of the process. The temperature of the system remained constant and heat uniformly entered into or out of the entire spatial region.

But in real processes, heat can only flow with a temperature difference. How can heat flow uniformly (and instantaneously) throughout an entire a spatial region when that system has no internal temperature differences (no internal gradients)?

We must invoke the hypothetical assumption that the heat flow occurs reversibly. This allows the heat to flow between two locations even as they have the same temperature. Conceptually, the internal heat flow is occurring between any two micro-regions inside the system, those micro-regions are at the same temperature even as they exchange heat, the temperatures of those micro-regions do not change during the process of exchanging heat, and the heat transfer occurs instantaneously throughout all such micro-regions.

This defines how an isothermal heat transfer process is also one that is internally reversible.

Comment: A comment to my own major revision: I removed much confusion by the recognition of time and space in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your textbook's statement is exactly, and in which context it's made. But the isolated statement "isothermal heat transfer processes are internally reversible" is false: they can be reversible or irreversible.

Take a small element within a material (I suppose that's what's mean by "internally"). The second law for this element is
$$\dot{S} \ge -\nabla\cdot \frac{\pmb{q}}{T} + \frac{Q}{T} \ ,$$
where $S$ is the entropy of the element, $\dot{S}$ the rate of change of this entropy, $\pmb{q}$ the heat flux vector (expressing contact heating), $Q$ the volume heating (eg radiative heating, as in a microwave for example), positive if it's received by the element, and $T$ is the temperature.

The process is said to be reversible, in some interval of time, if the inequality above is actually a strict equality, that is we can replace "$\ge$ with "$=$", during that interval of time. If it's a strict inequality instead, that is we can replace "$\ge$ with "$>$" for at least some times in that interval, then the process is said to be irreversible.

Now you see from the equation above that even if $T$ is constant in time (isothermal process, $\dot{T}=0$), or constant in space (uniform temperature, $\nabla T=0$), or both, we can't deduce in general that the equality "$=$" holds strictly. So an isothermal heat-transfer process can in general be either reversible or irreversible, in any part of the material you're considering.

Additional conditions must be specified to conclude that the process is reversible, that is, that the equal sign "$=$" applies in the second law above.

You can check for example

- Astarita: [*Thermodynamics: An Advanced Textbook for Chemical Engineers*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4899-0771-4) (Springer 1990), chaps 1–2
- Samohýl, Pekar: [*The Thermodynamics of Linear Fluids and Fluid Mixtures*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-02514-8) (Springer 2014), chaps 2–3

or any good book on thermomechanics/thermochemistry.